# Post request in JavaScript behaves unpredictable

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, post, request

I am trying to make a simple (or so I thought) Cordova app using HTML + JS. However, I'm getting completely unreasonable behavior. For the login I'm sending a POST request to an external server using data that I collect from an HTML form. I then show the response in an alert. This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
        <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
        <title>UrbanGO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form name="login" onsubmit="return validateLogin()">
                <div class="center-div"><h1>Login</h1></div>
                <div class="flex-row">
                    <div><label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label></div>
                    <!-- <div><input class="input-text" type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required></div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="flex-row">
                    <div><label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label></div>
                    <!-- <div><input class="input-text" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required></div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="center-div"><input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit" /></div>
                <div class="center-div"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember">Remember me</input></div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my *validateLogin()* script:

```
function validateLogin() {
    email = document.forms["login"]["email"].value;
    pwd = document.forms["login"]["pwd"].value;

    function showResponse() {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.addEventListener("load", showResponse)

    data = JSON.stringify({'email':email, 'password': pwd});
    
    xhttp.open("POST", "https://servername.ext/path", true);
   
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("accept-language", "[object Object]");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("app-version", "1.0.3");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("user-agent", "okhttp/4.9.1");
    
    xhttp.send(data)
}
```

When I enter the correct email and password in the HTML form I get an authorization back from the server which is shown in the alert. However, When I put the wrong password/email combination, no alert is shown. But the server does respond, I tested this in python.

I then tried commenting the top two lines of my JS script and manually setting *email* and *pwd* to wrong values. My script now looks like this:

```
function validateLogin() {
    // email = document.forms["login"]["email"].value;
    // pwd = document.forms["login"]["pwd"].value;

    email = "test@test.nl";
    pwd = "asdasdasd";

    ...

}
```

I then still got no alert. However, by chance I found out that when I remove the two input elements in the HTML code, it works and I get the "bad email/pwd combination" error. But the two values are not even read anymore by my script! So commenting two lines that have nothing to with my script anymore fixes things?!

Please advice. Also if someone could tell me how to debug JS code that would be amazing. Because the console in Chrome won't even throw an error when I call functions that do not exist so I have no feedback whatsoever and no debugging help at all.

Btw, I'm aware that HTML has a builtin post option for forms. But I need to be able to handle the post request myself in JS. For one, the data needs to be provided in JSON format and for future work I will need to edit POST requests some with data that is not provided through a form.

Comment: Use the Network tab of the browser to see what you're sending in the AJAX request and what response the server is sending.

Comment: `"accept-language", "[object Object]"` 

Comment: The accept language header is what the server expects. Besides, it works fine in python.